# How to create a shortcut for jumping through methods?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

It's possible to jump through methods on WebStorm editor with a shortcut? if it's not possible, it's possible to develop my own behaviour for shortcut?

You can see the requested behaviour here:

```
// CARET STARTS HERE
function a() {

    function b() {

    }
    function c() {

    }
    function d() {

    }
}
```

Next Step The caret move to function a():

```
function a() { // CARET HERE

    function b() {

    }
    function c() {

    }
    function d() {

    }
}
```

Next Step the caret move to function b():

```
function a() { 

    function b() { // CARET HERE

    }
    function c() {

    }
    function d() {

    }
}
```

Next Step the caret move to function c():

```
function a() { 

    function b() { 

    }
    function c() { // CARET HERE

    }
    function d() {

    }
}
```

Next Step the caret move to function d():

```
function a() { 

    function b() { 

    }
    function c() { 

    }
    function d() { // CARET HERE

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this article address your issue?
 - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/navigating-between-methods-and-tags.html

Comment: No... because it's move the caret to the parent method